# How does freeing memory affect space complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

Consider the following *pseudocode*:

```
linked_list_node = ... //We have some linked list
while linked_list_node is not NULL //Iterate through it 
    node_copy = CopyNode(linked_list_node) //We allocate a new pointer and copy the node, which is O(1) space
    ... //Do something
    DeleteAndFree(node_copy) //We free the memory allocated at the beginning of the loop
    Next(linked_list_node) //Advance once
```

Let **N** be the *size of our linked list*

#### On the one hand

At each iteration of the loop, we used **O(1) space**, the loop is **N** iterations, which means that in total we allocated **O(N) space**

#### On the other hand

We never actually allocated *N nodes at the same time*, each time we allocated exactly one node, so, in theory, we only **O(1) Space**. In other words, if our machine only had 1 byte available in memory, it could allocate and delete that same byte *over and over again*, never running into a memory limit.

---

I found this question on stack overflow: [What is O(1) space complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260889/what-is-o1-space-complexity)

*From accepted answer:*

> However, if let's say for some reason the algorithm needs to allocate 'N' pointers when traversing a list of size N, ..., then the algorithm is considered to have a space complexity of O(N)

It seems like my algorithm doesn't satisfy this condition as I never actually use *N different pointers at the same time*, so it should be **O(1) Space**. However, it indeed requires *N allocating operations*, which could be why it is really **O(N) Space**

So, what is the space complexity of that and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be O(1) complexity. At each step you can say that your usage increases and decreases by 1, so net gain of 0 for each element. That said, this is kind of an odd solution, as you presumably could replace it with an implementation where you allocate a single node, and just copy each element into it. The two would be equivalent, and the latter is clearly O(1) space complexity.